# Debugging two project Rider

Tags: .net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider

Using Rider EAP OS X from JetBrains, is it possible to debug two .NET Core Web projets at the same time?

I tried to create two configuration, but when I start the second one, it stop the first and vice-versa.

In Visual Studio, we used to set "Multiple startups projects".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the "Run/Debug Configurations"-window you can create a new "Compound".
Create a new configuration and select which projects to start.

Comment: Please notice that you cannot point both of your projects to use the same console, but you can set external console for each of them which is quite neat. 
More information on that could be found [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/23/rundebug-configurations-rider/).

Comment: What of opening a Multiple .Net projects in Rider?

Comment: This is obsolete 2021. No more create compound

Comment: The template is still there, it is just not visible by default. When you click the + icon, just search for compound. It will pop up.